# <a> tag not working if i use jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am writing a html page which has 3 list items and a header which is an anchor tag with some page address as href attribute  and i am using jquery.mobile to display them as a list view . now on cliking this icon i am not navigating to the address specified in the href .instead if i open the link in a new tab using right click on the item . it is working . is there any way such that i can use this page on a mobile where on tapping the icon the page changes .. i have already tried $.mobile.changepage ..it is not working 
here is some code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body data-role="page">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="header">
           <span><a href="some other file">gameflow
           </a></span></div>
        <ui data-role="listview">
           <li data-icon="false">
              <a href="#">
                 <span class="left-list"><img src="some image"/></span>
                 <span class="middle-list"> Find us</span>
                 <span class="right-list"><img src="right arrow"/></span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                    same element as above 
            </li>
            <li>
                    same element as above 
            </li>
            </div>
        </div>
     </body>
   </html>
```

2 more list view items and close the page ..everything is working there i just need a way or a function to navigate to the 's hrefs on tap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For external page can you try like this.

```
<a href="page.html" rel="external">page link</a>
```